# Ошибка: A JNI error has occurred

Tags: java, maven, jetty

Начнем с того, что приложение больше тестовое чем рабочее.
Ошибка возникает при запуске приложения.
Использую сборщик maven.

- File pom.xml

  ```
   <project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>sskm.com</groupId>
  <artifactId>affxml-service</artifactId>
  <version>0.1.0</version>
      <build>
          <plugins>
              <plugin>
                  <!-- Build an executable JAR -->
                  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                  <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                  <version>3.0.2</version>
                  <configuration>
                      <archive>
                          <manifest>
                              <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                              <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                              <mainClass>main.Main</mainClass>
                          </manifest>
                      </archive>
                  </configuration>
              </plugin>
          </plugins>
      </build>
      <dependencies>
          <dependency>
              <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
              <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
              <version>2.3.20</version>
          </dependency>
          <dependency>
              <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
              <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
              <version>9.1.0.M0</version>
          </dependency>
          <dependency>
              <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
              <artifactId>jetty-webapp</artifactId>
              <version>9.1.0.M0</version>
          </dependency>
      </dependencies>
  </project>
  ```

Как видно из pom использую jetty.
Понимаю что ноги растут из CLASSPATH, но знания по java на данный момент крайне скупы. Если не ошибаюсь, нужно прописать в pom плагин install. Подскажите, в правильном ли направлении думаю, а лучше всего подскажите конкретно как решить данную ошибку при запуске.

Добавлю что при поиске решения проблемы "ручками" скопировал библиотеки jetty в папку ./lib

```
$ ls ./lib
freemarker-2.3.20.jar    jetty-security-9.1.0.M0.jar  jetty-util-9.1.0.M0.jar
jetty-http-9.1.0.M0.jar  jetty-server-9.1.0.M0.jar    jetty-webapp-9.1.0.M0.jar
jetty-io-9.1.0.M0.jar    jetty-servlet-9.1.0.M0.jar   jetty-xml-9.1.0.M0.jar
```

Собственно вся ошибка

```
$java -jar affxml-service-0.1.0.jar
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jetty/se
ver/HttpConfiguration$Customizer
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConfi
uration$Customizer
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 7 more
```

Comment: В ошибке вроде должно быть указано, какой конкретно класс не найден

Answer (score 1):

добавил в pom.xml и взлетело

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <transformers>
                            <transformer
                                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                <mainClass>main.Main</mainClass>
                            </transformer>
                        </transformers>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```